# ¿Cómo tener un LAMP utilizando las imagenes de Docker?

Tags: docker

Estoy haciendo pruebas con Docker y todo funciona correctamente, lo que no puedo lograr es unir dos contenedores.

Tengo las imagenes httpd, php y mysql oficiales de Docker, las tres funcionan bien, pero al levantar el servidor httpd no puedo utilizar PHP ni MySQL. Realicé varios intentos sin lograrlo.

¿Cómo debería crear mi contenedor httpd para utilizar los otros dos?

Esto es lo que tengo actualmente:

#### mis imágenes

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
httpd                   2.4                 fb2f3851a971        6 weeks ago         178 MB
mysql                   8.0                 a8a59477268d        5 weeks ago         445 MB
php                     7.2                 f94a7bbcc361        4 days ago          352 MB
postgres                9.5                 8c79bdeb2795        2 weeks ago         234 MB
```

### creación de los contenedores

```
$ docker run -d --name webserver -p 80:80 -v /home/roberto/docker/apache2/www/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/  httpd:2.4

$ docker run -d --name php72  php:7.2

$ docker run -d --name mysql8 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password  mysql:8.0
```

#### mis contenedores

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
18c41442f6fa        httpd:2.4           "httpd-foreground"       17 hours ago        Exited (0) 17 hours ago     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp  apache2
ce6f5998857e        php:7.2             "docker-php-entryp..."   18 hours ago        Exited (0) 18 hours ago                         php72
146b0d6478d1        mysql:8.0           "docker-entrypoint..."   4 days ago          Exited (0) 46 hours ago                         mysql8
```

#### contenedor funcionando

```
$ docker ps -a

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
18c41442f6fa        httpd:2.4           "httpd-foreground"   18 hours ago        Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   apache2
```

Gracias.

---

Realicé los siguientes cambios en los contenedores:

#### elimino los contenedores

```
$ docker stop apache2

$ docker rm php72

$ docker rm apache2
```

#### creo nuevos contenedores

```
$ docker run -d --name php72  php:7.2 tail -f /dev/null

$ docker run --detach --link php72 --name apache2 --publish 80:80 --volume /home/roberto/docker/apache2/www:/var/www/html httpd:2.4
```

Con esto logro tener los dos contenedores corriendo, pero apache2 no se comunica con php72

---

Siguiendo el consejo de **Jaime Roman**, estoy utilizando `docker-compose` pero sigo sin poder unir los dos contenedores.

Este es mi archivo `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2' 
services: 
  php:
    command: tail -F anything
    image: php:5.6
    restart: always

  apache: 
    image: httpd:2.4 
    links:
     - php 
    restart: always
    ports: 
     - 80:80 
    volumes:
     - /home/roberto/docker/apache2/www:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

y con `docker ps` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
2c64d8af1df2        httpd:2.4           "httpd-foreground"       4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   apache2_apache_1
6038c798de04        php:5.6             "docker-php-entryp..."   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                             apache2_php_1
```

lo cual demuestra que ambos contenedores están ejecutandose, si creo un archivo "index.html" funciona perfectamente, pero un "index.**php**" no funciona.

¿Qué me está faltando?

Comment: Ojalá puedan responderte, me ayudaría también a mi que ando con unos dolores de cabeza intentando generar un entorno similar al tuyo: apache + php7 + mariadb (sin utilizar el bundle de Bitnami) para generar un entorno de desarrollo en el cual utilizar el framework codeigniter.

Comment: Te está faltando decirle al apache (httpd) cómo procesar los archivos php.

Comment: Tienes un problema con el concepto que tienes de la relación entre Apache y PHP. Los sistemas LAMP tienen integrado PHP en Apache como módulo, de modo que no tienen un ejecutable para Apache y otro para PHP, si no un único Apache con el módulo de PHP activado. Por otro lado, puedes usar PHP-FPM para separar Apache de PHP, pero entonces necesitas agregar una configuración en Apache para indicar que los scripts PHP debe interpretarlos en el FPM. Así que te pregunto: ¿qué prefieres? ¿una solución basada en tres imágenes (apache + php-fpm + mysql) o una basada en dos imágenes (apache/php + mysql)?

Answer (score 1):

**re-edit**

Agrego 2 ejemplos (descargables desde github) para practicar configurar 2 versiones de php en un mismo dominio usando docker: uno con apache y otro con nginx.

https://github.com/aloMalbarez/docker-2php1apache

https://github.com/aloMalbarez/docker-2php1nginx

**Edit**

Para usar httpd (apache) por un lado y php en otra imagen/contenedor una de las formas es configurar apache para que levante php como fpm via proxy (es lo que permite tener php en "otra maquina")

Esto se logra de varias maneras, te pongo la mas simple usando docker-compose:

necesitamos 3 archivos y una carpeta con el source

```
/miproyecto
   /docker-compose.yml
   /httpd-min.conf
   /Dockerfile
   /source
       /index.php
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: httpd:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./source:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
      - ./httpd-min.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
    networks:
      - misitio-network

  php:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./source:/var/www/misitio
    networks:
      - misitio-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: miclaveROOTdemysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: unadatabase
      MYSQL_USER: unusuariodemysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: laclavedeladatabase
    networks:
      - misitio-network

networks:
  misitio-network:
    driver: bridge
```

en `services`, `web` le digo que monte mi código fuente (`source`) en el root de apache, y que reemplaze la configuración del apache con mi configuración (`httpd-min.conf`) que es la que le dice que haga proxy con el php

en `services`, `php` le digo que monte mi código fuente (`source`) en una carpeta que es la que le defino en la configuracion del apache (ver `httpd-min.conf`), y que además use el `Dockerfile` para habilitar extensiones (pdo_mysql para acceder a la db)

en `services`, `db` uso la versión 5.7 para evitar tener que hacer configuración extra del php y el mysql (en versión 8 cambia el default auth y da error de login)

`networks` define una red para enlazar los services

`Dockerfile`

```
 FROM php:7-fpm
 RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Aquí le digo que habilite la extensión pdo para mysql

`httpd-min.conf`

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
Listen 80
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so

LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
ServerAdmin you@example.com
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>
ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /proc/self/fd/1 common
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>
<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

# mi sitio

ServerName pruebalamp.local
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/var/www/misitio/$1
  DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

un httpd.conf básico con el agregado al final del virtualhost que hace el proxypass sólo para php, sirviendo los archivos estáticos directamente (por eso montamos el source en ambas imagenes)

`source/index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Archivo PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "Hola! soy PHP".PHP_EOL; ?><br/>
<?php
    $DB_HOST = "db";
    $DB_NAME = 'unadatabase';
    $DB_USER = "unusuariodemysql";
    $DB_PASS = "laclavedeladatabase";

    // PDO
    try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_NAME", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      echo "[PDO] conectado a la DB con éxito";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo "[PDO] conexión a la DB falló: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?><br/>
    <?php echo "algo de info:".PHP_EOL; ?><br/>
    <?php phpinfo(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

un php simple que hace la conexión a la db y muestra phpinfo

la secuencia inicial es:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up
```

Para recrear las imagenes si cambias versiones:

```
$ sudo docker-compose rm -f
$ sudo docker-compose pull
$ sudo docker-compose up --build
```

Si no requerís de una db, o extensiones extra de php el `docker-compose.yml` se simplifica, y no necesitas del `Dockerfile`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: httpd:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./source:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
      - ./httpd-min.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
    networks:
      - misitio-network

  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./source:/var/www/misitio
    networks:
      - misitio-network

networks:
  misitio-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Debajo dejo la respuesta original

---

No hace falta tener contenedores separados, 
lamp lo tenes todo junto en varios contenedores por ejemplo:

`$ sudo docker pull greyltc/lamp` archlinux

`$ sudo docker pull fauria/lamp` ubuntu 14/16

hay otros con mas o menos detalles, varias versiones etc, es cuestion de ir viendo cual te sirve en la página detalle

https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=1&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=lamp&starCount=0

Por otro lado y sumando al comentario de @Huskie, para armar un custom build podrías usar un `Dockerfile` con `FROM php:7-apache`, y asi tener un sistema base php7+apache, el mariadb/mysql lo podes incluir en el proyecto via `docker-compose.yml` como otro servicio linkeado.

`Dockerfile`
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

`docker-compose.yml`
https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Comment: Es cierto lo que dices, pero a mi me interesa tener las imágenes por separado para aprender a usarlas. Quiero lograr mi propósito y así poder utilizar la misma imagen httpd con diferentes versiones de php según sea mi necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estas teniendo es de red, no de contenedores. Cuando levantas un contenedor puedes acceder a él desde tu pc como **localhost**, o sea, para acceder al contenedor de http basta lenvantar un navegador y poner **http://localhost** y ya está, **nota: no he puesto el puerto pq los navegadores utilizan el 80 por defecto, en caso que utilizaras otro tendrías que poner http://localhost:puerto**.

Ahora bien, el problema está en que desde un contenedor no puedes acceder a otro contenedor como **localhost**, por ejemplo, mysql utiliza por defecto el puerto **3306**, si vas a acceder desde el contenedor de http al mysql no puedes decir **localhost:3306** porque no va a encontrar el destino.

A cada contenedor se le asigna una IP en la red privada de docker, debes conocer la ip de cada uno de tus contenedores para poder acceder desde un contenedor a otro.

Hay dos posibles soluciones para esto:

**1. La primera:** Dado que ya conoces los IDs de tus contenedores abre un terminal y escribe: `docker inspect <ID contenedor>`, por ejemplo si quieres inspeccionar el contenedor de mysql escribes `docker inspect 146b0d6478d1`. Ahí mostrará todo sobre ese contenedor, al final de la descripción está la parte que te informa de la red del contenedor, algo similar a esto:
[image: descripcion de red de un contenedor docker]

Donde **IPAddress** es la ip del contendor que estás inspeccionando, en este caso tu mysql, **Gateway** sería la ip de tu pc, si haces este proceso a varios contenedores te darás cuenta que el **Gateway** es el mismo en todos porque esa es tu pc física y esta es la ip a la que tienes que navegar, o sea, si quieres acceder desde el contenedor de http al contendor de mysql, entonces en el http deberías poner `<Gateway>:<puerto mysql>`, o sea,  `192.19.0.1:3306`

**2. La segunda(te la recomiendo mejor):** puedes utilizar **docker-compose** que te permite poner toda la configuración inicial que van a tener los contenedores, y todos se "conocerán" porque están conectados directamente en la misma red. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de un **docker-compose**

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.6   
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"

  app:
    image: silex
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Aquí estoy creando dos contenedores, uno con postgres y uno con silex, pero da igual lo que levantes, lo más importante aqui es que en el contenedor de **silex** estoy linkeando al de postgres, si te fijas donde pone `links: - postgres`, ahora puedes entrar al contenedor de silex abrir un terminal y poner `ping postgres` y verás cómo conoce la ip de dicho contenedor.

Comment: Gracias Jaime, tu mensaje me sirvió mucho, todavía no logro que funcione pero seguiré investigando por aquí.

Comment: Por qué no funciona todavía, ¿que pasa ahora?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema en el `docker-compose.yml` es que no identificas que servicios dependen de que. Por ejemplo:

```
   version: '2'
   services:
     web:
      depends_on:
        - db
        - php
       image: httpd:latest
       ports:
         - "8080:80"
       volumes:
         - ./source:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
         - ./httpd-min.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
       networks:
         - misitio-network

     php:
      depends_on:
        - db
       build: .
       volumes:
         - ./source:/var/www/misitio
       networks:
         - misitio-network

     db:
       image: mysql:5.7
       restart: always
       environment:
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: miclaveROOTdemysql
         MYSQL_DATABASE: unadatabase
         MYSQL_USER: unusuariodemysql
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: laclavedeladatabase
       networks:
         - misitio-network
```

Por lo menos en wordpress mediante el archivo docker-compose lo indica de ese modo, wordpress container depende de mysql container.

Comment: Si a apache no le decís como manejar archivos .php te los va a mostrar como texto. Ese es todo el problema. Tanto en mi ejemplo como en el .yml que pones hay una línea que configura el apache para que reconozca a php -> `- ./httpd-min.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`. En el caso de la imagen docker de wordpress ya trae un apache+php configurado. misma situación que la otra respuesta donde usa la imagen `silex`

Comment: En wordpress la configuración que comentas, supongo que va interna como bien dices, ya que esa linea simplemente la he dejado en el ejemplo, porque me ha parecido que a tu respuesta simplemente le faltaba añadir el depends_on. Gracias por tu comentario!! :)

Comment: el `depends_on` se usa mas que nada par definir el orden de arranque y en cierta forma también para "cascadear" los builds

Answer (score 0):

Estás cometiendo un error de interpretación en el funcionamiento habitual de una pila AMP (LAMP y WAMP). Por norma general todas suelen tener PHP integrado en el servidor Apache como módulo de éste, por lo que son un único componente indivisible.

Para continuar, estás usando la imagen incorrecta de docker. Por si no lo sabías la imagen `php:7.2` es para ejecutar código PHP en símbolo de sistema (CLI) y no a través de un servidor web.

Puedes comprobarlo comparando los resúmenes (digest) sha256 de cada imagen:

- php:7.2: [`c5ddf81fd8545d0dc8f1c1d2d50e12ebf18b23c459d0efd23e66a0110ff9ace2`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2/images/sha256-c5ddf81fd8545d0dc8f1c1d2d50e12ebf18b23c459d0efd23e66a0110ff9ace2?context=explore)
- php:7.2-buster: [`c5ddf81fd8545d0dc8f1c1d2d50e12ebf18b23c459d0efd23e66a0110ff9ace2`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2-buster/images/sha256-c5ddf81fd8545d0dc8f1c1d2d50e12ebf18b23c459d0efd23e66a0110ff9ace2?context=explore)
- php:7.2-cli: [`c5ddf81fd8545d0dc8f1c1d2d50e12ebf18b23c459d0efd23e66a0110ff9ace2`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2-cli/images/sha256-c5ddf81fd8545d0dc8f1c1d2d50e12ebf18b23c459d0efd23e66a0110ff9ace2?context=explore)

Las tres imágenes son la misma imagen con diferentes etiquetas (tags). Es decir, esta imagen **no sirve para servir páginas web**.

Para ese propósito tienes dos alternativas:

- Servidor web Apache con PHP como módulo: [php:7.2-apache](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2-apache/images/sha256-2f40d666588f04b1b331fa23d0bda96fa0b4079893c46c292fd2c4d92386a145?context=explore).
- Trabajadores PHP-FPM independientes: [php:7.2-fpm](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2-fpm/images/sha256-49e30de91684104eff43562134ea95cf407a5dd62417a8a2b6f8067d2df94be5?context=explore).

Con la primera solución tendrás Apache y PHP funcional sin ninguna configuración, pero si quieres usar trabajadores FPM entonces tendrás que instalar un servidor Apache o NGINX y realizar la configuración en él necesaria para que sepa que debe pasar el trabajo de los PHP al FPM.

Es decir, que si quieres separar el contenedor del servidor web Apache del de los trabajadores PHP-FPM necesitarás personalizar la configuración interna el contenedor docker del servidor web Apache, no funcionará "automágicamente" con los valores por defecto.

Ejemplo del archivo `/etc/apache2/conf-available/php7.2-fpm.conf`:

```
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Habilitar cabezadas de autorización HTTP
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml)$">
        # Por defecto estará accesible desde localhost
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
        # Si usas docker-compose tendrás que indicar el nombre del servicio
        #SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://php:9000"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Por defecto denegar el acceso al código fuente
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Denegar el acceso a archivos que solo tengan extensión (como '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[3457]?|t|tml|ps)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Además, deberías exponer el puerto `9000` del trabajador PHP-FPM para que el servidor Apache pueda contactar con él y montar exactamente el mismo volumen que en el servidor web:

```
docker run -d --name php72 \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    -v /home/roberto/docker/apache2/www/:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ \
     php:7.2-fpm
```