# Aplicación de docker en entorno de producción

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker

He estado investigando sobre el funcionamiento de docker y el gran potencial que tiene. Después de estar estudiando unos días el sistema, he estado haciendo unas pruebas creando mi propia imagen desde fichero con un servidor apache, php7.2 y ubuntu18.04 (que por cierto no he conseguido que se inicie el apache al lanzar el container,solo puedo hacerlo desde bash).

La manera de lanzar el container es mapeando en mis pruebas el puerto local 8000 con el puerto 80 del contenedor. Por lo tanto al entrar en la máquina real por el puerto 8000 (http://localhost:8000) conecta al Apache del contendor por el 80.

Este es mi fichero Dockerfile que he configurado para tal tarea:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV php_conf /etc/php/7.2/fpm/
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
MAINTAINER Albert Sánchez
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get -y install sudo
RUN useradd -m ubuntu && echo "ubuntu:ubuntu" | chpasswd && adduser ubuntu sudo
RUN echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
CMD /bin/bash
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN  echo "Europe/Madrid" > /etc/timezone
RUN  apt-get install nano -y
RUN  apt-get install  apache2 php7.2 supervisor php7.2 php7.2-mysql  php7.2-common php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml -y
EXPOSE 80
RUN  echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN  service apache2 restart
CMD apt-get -y install curl
RUN  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Entonces mi duda viene aquí, he conseguido que funcione correctamente, pero ¿realmente es el uso que se le quiere dar a un servidor en producción? He visto ejemplos de deploy de Apps con mucha menos configuración que esta o bien muy distinta, incluso si configuración del servidor web.

¿Deberían estar los componentes separados por contenedores? ¿ Por ejemplo un contenedor con php, otro con el apache, otro con el proyecto web?

- [Docker para dummies](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/docker-for-dummies/)
- [Documentación official Docker](https://docs.docker.com/)

Comment: también podes usar una imagen `FROM php:apache` que ya tiene el apache corriendo con php via modulo, hay una lista de los diferentes tags en https://hub.docker.com/_/php/ . 
Para tener apache y php en diferentes contenedores tenes que configurar apache para que procese los .php via proxy fpm, hay un ejemplo de esto último en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172411/81450

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En efecto todo junto así está bien. Lo que suele estar separado es por ejemplo si tienes una base de datos en un contenedor o si tienes un servicio de caché como Redis.

Por otro, lado el uso que le das al CMD es incorrecto. CMD es para definir con qué comando arrancará el contenedor, ahí es donde le dices que levante el Apache. Limpié un poco tu Dockerfile quitando cosas necesarias o convenientes para una máquina física pero no para un contenedor:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER Albert Sánchez


ENV php_conf /etc/php/7.2/fpm/
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN echo "Europe/Madrid" > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get -yq update
RUN apt-get -yq install nano -y
RUN apt-get -yq install  apache2 php7.2 supervisor php7.2 php7.2-mysql  php7.2-common php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xml -y
EXPOSE 80

RUN  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Aún así el apache no levanta ya que necesita algunas variables de ambiente que tiene en su script de arranque.

Aunque puedes hacer todo el trabajo para que levante, yo te recomiendo basarte en una imagen base oficial de php:

```
FROM php:7-apache
MAINTAINER Albert Sánchez

#Quitar esto es solopara probar
RUN echo "Hola"> index.html

# src es una carpeta que está al lado del Dockerfile que tiene todo tu codigo
#COPY src/ /var/www/html/
```

Aquí dice como se usa: https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Comment: Gracias me ha resultado de mucha ayuda! sobretodo el comando para arrancar apache, saludos

Comment: De nada que le aproveches. Recomiendo usar una imagen oficial base php así no tienes que hacer tantas cosas, pero es muy bueno para aprender. Por ejemplo puedes usar `FROM php:7-apache`

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la edición, se ve mucho mejor y yo escribí todo rápido desde el teléfono antes de salir de la casa.

Comment: Faltaría más :) Siempre es buena noticia que un usuario experimentado se una al sitio!

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez Aré una prueba con la imagen que me muestras y comento las impresiones, pero de entrada buena pinta! saludos.

Comment: Hola @CarlosRafaelRamirez Estuve probando el comando CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]  al final del Dockerfile pero no arranca apache2. Tal como dijiste he probado de cambiar el CMD /bin/bash por run y dejar el CMD de apache pero compila con errores.

Puede que sea por un tema de como arranco la imagen? Mis pasos son: 
- docker run -d -it -p 8000:80 id_imagen bash.
- docker ps
-docker start id_container
-docker exec -it id_container bash

Igual estoy cometiendo un fallo en estos puntos.

Comment: @albert-sanchez-guerrero Actualicé mi respuesta con mi recomendación que no es otra que utilizar la imagen de php ya configurada. Y la imagen la deberias arrancar `docker run -d -p 8000:80 id_imagen`. `-d` y `-it` no son compatibles. Si le pones el bash al final sobreescribes el comando que está en el Dockerfile. Eso tiene otro usos pero no para levantar un servicio web

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración @CarlosRafaelRamirez, la idea es también poder tener acceso por consola y bueno configurar ftp y todos los servicios que se suelen usar para un servidor web. Saludos