# ¿Desplegar multiples versiones de php en contenedores separados de docker?(Refactorizar Entorno de Desarrollo)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, refactoring

***(Refactorizar Entorno de Desarrollo)***

La refactorización (del inglés refactoring) es una técnica de la ingeniería de software para reestructurar un código fuente, alterando su estructura interna sin cambiar su comportamiento externo.

***Tengo la siguiente estructura en docker: (Esto es un ejemplo hipotetico)***

```
Docker Network
│
├── Proxy Server Container: Manage Custom URL like https://test.dock 
├── MySql Server
├── php8.2 + PhpMyadmin
├── Project 1 server: php 7.2 + code repository
├── Project 2 server: php 7.2 + code repository
├── Project 3 server: php 8.2 + code repository
├── Project 4 server: php 8.2 + code repository
```

***Quisiera cambiar mi estructura y separar las versiones de php: (Esto es un ejemplo hipotetico)***

```
Docker Network
│
├── Proxy Server Container: Manage Custom URL like https://test.dock 
├── MySql Server
├── PhpMyadmin
├── php 7.2
├── php 8.2
├── PhpMyadmin
├── Project 1 server: code repository
├── Project 2 server: code repository
├── Project 3 server: code repository
├── Project 4 server: code repository
```

**Estos son los archivos yml:**

ejemplo de webserver.yml

```yml
version: "3.9"

services:

  webserver:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Web-Server-XX-2
    build:
      context: ./bin/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.secure
      args:
        - XX_PHP_VERSION=8.2
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    volumes:
      - ./../project:/var/www/html:rw
      - ./../project/public:/var/www/html/public:rw
      - ./config/vhost:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./config/cron:/etc/cron-task
      - ./data/cron:/data/cron
      - ./log/apache2:/var/log/apache2
      - ./log/cron:/var/log/cron
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: XX-2.dock,cron.XX-2.dock
      XX_WEB_MASTER: XX@XX.com
      XX_APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
      XX_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /public
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "XX-stack.webserver.description=Web Server"
      - "XX-stack.webserver.role=webserver"
    privileged: true
    tty: true

networks:
  lamp-network:
    external: true
```

ejemplo de proxy.yml

```yml
version: "3.9"

services:

  reverse-proxy:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: Proxy-Server
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - webserver
      - phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect
      - TRUST_DOWNSTREAM_PROXY=true
      - ENABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./config/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    privileged: true
    tty: true

networks:
  lamp-network:
    external: true
```

ejemplo de database.yml

```yml
version: "3.9"

services:

  database:
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: MySql-Server
    restart: always
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: #############
      MYSQL_DATABASE: XX-2
      MYSQL_USER: tester
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: #############
    labels:
      - "XX-stack.database.description=Database Server"
      - "XX-stack.database.role=database"
      
  phpmyadmin:
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: phpMyAdmin-Server
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: pma.XX-stack.dock
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: #############
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: #############
      MYSQL_USER: tester
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: #############
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 512M
      MEMORY_LIMIT: 512M
    volumes:
      - /sessions
      - ./config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - lamp-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    labels:
      - "XX-stack.phpmyadmin.description=phpMyAdmin"
      - "XX-stack.phpmyadmin.role=phpmyadmin"

networks:
  lamp-network:
    external: true
```

Ejemplo del DockerFile para web server, donde se encuentra la version de apache y php:

```
ARG XX_PHP_VERSION

FROM php:${LH_PHP_VERSION}-apache-bullseye

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update &&  \
    apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --fix-missing tzdata sed build-essential dialog nano apt-utils cron wget git curl zip openssl gettext-base libnss3-tools

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean

RUN a2enmod http2
RUN a2enmod proxy
RUN a2enmod proxy_http
RUN a2enmod rewrite 
RUN a2enmod ssl 
RUN a2enmod headers 
RUN a2enmod proxy_wstunnel

RUN service apache2 restart

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/cron && \
    chmod 755 /var/log/cron

CMD cat /etc/cron-task/new-task >> /etc/cron.d/cron-task && \
    chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-task && \
    touch /var/log/cron/cron.log && \
    cron && \
    chmod +x /etc/cron-task/crontab-ui.sh && \
    /etc/cron-task/crontab-ui.sh && \
    /usr/local/bin/apache2-foreground && \
    tail -f /var/log/cron/cron.log
```

***Mi consulta:***

Necesito refactorizar mis archivos yml antes mencionados pero no encuentro que cambios debo hacer en la programacion/parametrizacion para conseguirlo la idea de esto es poder separar las dependencias y poder hacerlas reutilizables.

***Update***

He estado investigando un poco más a profundidad he llegado a la conclusion de que ***no*** necesito que: Project 1, 2 ,3 y 4 sean contenedores ... pueden ser directorios de la red a los que el contenedor de la version de PHP tenga acceso, el objetivo es que cada vez que se agregue un directorio nuevo de un proyecto tendria que alterar/actualizar y refrescar el contenedor proxy y el contenedor de la version de php asociada para incluir la URL custom ... es un tema de mecanica o proceso de despliegue y comandos con los que se levantan y refrescan los contenedores en docker ... con algo de configuración. estare trabajando en mi propia solución.

Comment: fijate https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172411/81450 como configurar varios php en distintos contenedores, el OP de esa pregunta no llegó a comprender como es la relación entre apache y php pero hay varios ejemplos de como "enganchar" dif versiones de php a un mismo webserver, en tu caso habría que ver si ademas del proxy (nginx) pones un apache que sirva de glue entre : los proyectos y los php o si configuras cada proyecto en el proxy ( apache/nginx con php-fpm funciona basicamente como proxy/proxy reverso ).

Comment: 2/ lo scripteable sería decirle al contenedor del webserver (apache/nginx) donde montar los archivos ( del proyecto X ) y configurarle que pool / ip:puerto de fpm usar para cada punto de montaje

Comment: si claro, en teoría cada contenedor que ejecuta php lleva un servidor apache... creo que debería mostrarte el dockerfile qué se inicia en el webserver

Comment: @aloMalbarez ya he agregado el contenido de dockerfile y como esta el deploy de apache... no se si se deja ver que quisiera tener separado el contenedor con los servicios web de el codigo fuente del proyecto, en pocas palabra los contenedores proyectos 1, 2 , 3 ... etc deben pasar a ser simplemente document root o repositorios de codigo ...

Comment: si estas interesado en el seguimiento a este proyecto te comento que en realidad implemento un lanzador desde un script en powershell que se encarga de armar practicamente todo ... preguntando cosas basicas... como dominio, usuario, contraseña ...

Comment: @aloMalbarez estoy investigando y no necesito que: Project 1, 2 ,3  y 4 sean contenedores ... pueden ser directorios, el tema es que cada vez que se agregue un directorio nuevo de un proyecto tendria que alterar/actualizar y refrescar el contenedor proxy y el contenedor de la version de php asociada para incluir la URL custom ...

Comment: creo que la mecanica es mas sencilla, que agregar contenedores nuevos etc ...